# Overfull \hbox when typing inline Math equations. Can we make it adaptive to go to the next line?

Tags: formatting

Hey guys so below is my Tex command:

```latex
\subsection{Bicubic Interpolation}
This is an extension of the cubic interpolation method in a two dimensional regular grid. 
Given the function values $f$ and the derivatives $f_x$, $f_y$ and $f_{xy}$ are known at the four corners 
around the four corners $(0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)$ of the unit square. 
The interpolated surface can then be expressed as:
```

Comment: the ,` between your coordinates like the comma between f_x and f_y  would be better out of math as part of the sentence, then it would linebreak as you intend

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  But what is the question?

Comment: You might also think about \sloppy or \raggedright to avoid overfull \hbox, same as with text.

Answer (score 4):

Inline math just beaks at infix binary operators (like +) or relations (like =) or explicit linebreak penalties added by `\linebreak[2]` or similar commands.

But here the list of coordinates is part of the sentence structure not mathematics so just as the comma after `$f_x$` you can mark it up with text commas so you get normal sentence comman spaces and line break possibilities:

```
$(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$
```